# just trying to submit a form

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cURL: Just trying to download a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340377/curl-just-trying-to-download-a-page)

I'm trying to submit [this](http://www.tourism.verona.it/_vti_g1_srSf.aspx?rpstry=3_) form without filling any field using cURL.

I've tried this:

```
<?php

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.tourism.verona.it/_vti_g1_srSf.aspx?rpstry=3_';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,0);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

but the output is just the same page (I expected the page that is showed after submit the form and that contains a list of hotels).

Comment: They are using the Post-Redirect-Get pattern (PRG) so you can just do a GET to the resultant URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt"); //make sure apache is able to write
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); //make sure apache is able to write
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");


CURLOPT_POST - to make a POST request
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS - to send POST data
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION - for dealing with redirect.
```

the other 3 are useful with most of the websites and you better use cookies then trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.tourism.verona.it/_vti_g1_srSf.aspx?rpstry=3_';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'var1=value1;var2=value2');

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can submit the form manually without filling in the details, the fields are still sent to the server.

A check server side that the fields are set will fail if you don't pass them:

```
if (isset($_POST['srSearchForm:lstStruttura'])) { ...
```

In addition, they are using a POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern to redirect you after the post to a GET url. Maybe you could just do the final get to http://www.tourism.verona.it/_vti_g1_srSr.aspx?rpstry=3_ as this circumvents the entire need to POST.

Comment: I'm trying to to follow this example: http://php.dzone.com/news/execute-http-post-using-php-cu , but I don't know where $last_name, $first_name, $title are created/set...any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting all the post-variables set that need to be set? Check on their page what values you need to fill in the form to be sure!

Comment: how can I know the values I need to fill? but do i really need to give that?? You know I can submit the form without filling anything..

Comment: Yes you can, but the fields will then be set to be empty and still be there. So without them at all the request could probably fail.