# cURL: Just trying to download a page

Tags: php, curl

I have this code:

```
include('./simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');


$url = "http://www.turismovenezia.it/Dove-Alloggiare/1322597142.html";  
$ch = curl_init();  

// set URL and other appropriate options  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

// grab URL and pass it to the browser  

$output = curl_exec($ch);  

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

but I'm not getting anything as output..I expected the code of the page ($url).

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: (This part of) your code is fine.

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340210/just-trying-to-submit-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use file_get_contents for a remote file, it is slow, inefficient, CPU intensive. Use Curl or fsocket instead... fsocket being the better of of the two.

Comment: Did you know that using `file_get_contents` can mean that you're via PHP internals actually using curl?

Answer (score 4):

Easier to use is:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://www.turismovenezia.it/Dove-Alloggiare/1322597142.html");
?>
```

But tested this function, tested and works, which if found on: http://4rapiddev.com/php/php-get-webpage-content-using-curl/ :

```
function get_webpage_content($webpage_url)
{
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$webpage_url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    return $html;
}
```

Maybe you had to use 1, instead of true, but I thought you could use both.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.turismovenezia.it/Dove-Alloggiare/1322597142.html");
$path = "PATH WHERE YOU HAVE TO STORE";
file_put_contents($content,$path);
```